# Oracle connection manager

Tags: oracle

I am considering introducing Oracle Connection Manager into my network architecture. This should allow me to manage access of specific hosts to the database. Could experienced users say if Connection Manager is widely used?Or maybe it has bad reputability?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems you are thinking about a user management module to your project. It's not strictly related with Oracle, when you design a user management module you can allow or block any action of any user in your project.